# DynamoDB Table Design: How do I model a one to many relationship where I need all of the "one" items and one of "many" sorted by some attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-data-modeling

I've spent my entire career working with denormalized relational databases. I am having a hard time un-learning all of that in order to implement a single-table design that can handle a couple specific access patterns on an "App Store"-like personal project.

[Here's a quick ERD.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzoiB.png) There is an App model identified by a platform (iOS, Android) and bundle identifier along with a Defaults map that is used when creating new versions. Each App can have 0 to many Versions which are identified by a version number (which is a sequential numerical value and is unique within the context of an App).  A version has an IsReleased attribute along with several others (like Name, Release Notes, Binary Path, etc).

**Access Patterns**

1. List the latest version of every app.
2. List the latest version of every app for a given platform.
3. List the latest version of every app where IsReleased is 1.
4. List the latest version of every app for a given platform where IsReleased is 1.
5. Get the latest version of a specific app.
6. Get the latest version of a specific app where IsReleased is 1.
7. Get all versions of a specific app.
8. Get all versions of a specific app where IsReleased is 1.
9. Get the Default attribute for a specific app.

I'm having trouble with 1 though 4, this table is where I was headed.  I'm having a hard time coming with a GSIs that will give me the all of the *app* items with a single *version* by sort order.

| pk | sk | Defaults | App Name | Version | IsReleased | Other Attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `app_ios_com.app.one` | `defaults` | `{ ... json ... }` |  |  |  |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.one` | `version_1` |  | App One | 1 | 1 |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.one` | `version_2` |  | App One | 2 | 1 |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.one` | `version_3` |  | App One | 3 | 1 |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.two` | `defaults` | `{ ... json ... }` |  |  |  |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.two` | `version_1` |  | App Two | 1 | 1 |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.two` | `version_2` |  | App Two | 2 | 0 |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.two` | `version_3` |  | App Two | 3 | 0 |  |

For example, for access pattern 1, I want:

| pk | sk | Defaults | App Name | Version | IsReleased | Other Attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `app_ios_com.app.one` | `version_3` |  | App One | 3 | 1 |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.two` | `version_3` |  | App Two | 3 | 0 |  |

For example, for access pattern 3, I would want:

| pk | sk | Defaults | App Name | Version | IsReleased | Other Attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `app_ios_com.app.one` | `version_2` |  | App One | 3 | 1 |  |
| `app_ios_com.app.two` | `version_1` |  | App Two | 1 | 1 |  |

Some data constraints that I have to keep in mind:

- There are currently only 10 to 20 apps, but I need to be able to support hundreds
- Most apps will have 100 to 200 versions with 20 to 30 released versions.  The biggest app has 1000 versions of which 50 are released.
- In the back-end, the IsReleased flag will typically be toggled from 0 to 1, but will occasionally be toggled from 0 to 1.
- The average version item is approximately 2 KB.
- The access pattern variations where IsReleased is 1 are more frequently used by a significant margin.

I feel like the solution is right in front of me, but I can't put my finger on it.

Comment: DynamoDB isn't a good choice for this use case; you really need to know the partition key(s) you'll be accessing ahead of time in order for it to be effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;**  The solution that springs to mind is a [leaderboard pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-gaming-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) to cache the latest app versions in separate record(s).  Whenever a new version is added, [DynamoDB Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/) sends the change as an event to lambda, which then updates the denormalised Latest records.

**Note**:  One piece of information was missing from your excellent write-up:  how often do you need to perform the `latest` queries?  If not very often, then "scan-and-done" will be OK for your current volumes.  If the answer is 1k `latest` queries per minute, then it's a different story. The good news is that your basic table design is solid.  `Latest` query optimisation can be implemented incrementally when performance/cost problems arise, without messing with the table design.

##### Denormalising the Latest Versions

We will keep denormalised copie(s) of the latest versions, another sinful-sounding [DynamoDB pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/should-your-dynamodb-table-be-normalized-or-denormalized/).  The Stream-triggered lambda will update those records using the update API when a version is added or changes release status.  How to store the latest version info?  We have several options:

1. Store all `latest` data in a singleton record with map attributes `{app1: {latest version copy}, app2: ...}`.  You can put more logic into the records to handle the `isReleased` items, or simply fetch the record and filter in your backend.
2. Use a Global Secondary Index with one record per app.  Each record has "latest" as the GSI1PK and GSI1SK of `app_id`.  The records
   have the same info as in #1.
3. Use as GSI with multiple records per app.  Something like this seems to work.  For instance, query #4 would use `GSI1PK=Latest#Released AND begins_with(GSI1SI, "IOS")`

```
GSI1PK              GSI1SK
Latest              app_ios_com.app.one
Latest              IOS#app_ios_com.app.one
Latest#Released     app_ios_com.app.one
Latest#Released     IOS#app_ios_com.app.one
```

**Note**:  If you have high query volumes and low cardinality, [hot partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-uniform-load.html) may be a problem for these "leaderboard" type deormalised patterns.  If this becomes a problem, you can address it by keeping multiple copies of each "latest" record, e.g. have X copies that are queried randomly `latest-copy1`, `latest-copy2`, `latest-copy3`.  Amazon calls this pattern [sharding using calculated suffixes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html#bp-partition-key-sharding-calculated).

Comment: Thank you for this response.  I did play with the idea of a “latest” GSI PK with a GSI SK of the platform#bundleid, but my self-doubt won over my persistence.  I think that will handle the the latest queries beautifully.